# Get ID of the newly inserted record, using SqlDataAdapter

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, sqldataadapter

```
BGREX.BGREXDataTable _bRexDataTable = new BGREX.BGREXDataTable();
BGREX.BGREXRow bgRexRow = _bRexDataTable.NewBGREXRow();

bgRexRow.BGRes_TITLE = "abc";
bgRexRow.BGRes_VERSION = 123;

_bRexDataTable.AddBGREXRow(bgRexRow);
int rewEffected = Adapter.Update(_bRexDataTable);
```

Have beed using above to insert record in Database, workes perfect. Now I need the id (Primary key) of newly  inserted record which is auto generated, instead of rows affected to be returned from

```
Adapter.Update(_bRexDataTable);
```

It looks like I need SCOPE_IDENTITY() function, but I am not sure where to include this in designer as designers is not happy with following syntax added to the actual insert query.
It woks fine in sqlserver Management console though

```
DECLARE @ROWI_D int

INSERT INTO TABLE
.....
.....
.....         
VALUES
("val1","val2",.......................)

SET ROW_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Comment: is the adapter insert command using a stored procedure or a sql statement directly?

Comment: SQL statement directly, not stored proceedure

Comment: How about @@Identity ?

Comment: What I Get is "The Declare SQL construct or statement is not supported.", In the Query Designer

Comment: **IF** you want to use something like that, make sure to use **SCOPE_IDENTITY()** ! You might experience unexpected and unwanted surprises otherwise......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'm not sure of a way to do this using sql statements with the commands. i'm not saying that it can't be done, i just never work with the statements, always through sprocs.

through the use of stored procedures you can define an output parameter which you can set equal to `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` in the sproc and then ensure that you pass that parameter into the command while settings it's direction as output.

sorry i don't have a solution for the direct sql call, but maybe someone else with more experience working in this way will chime in.

here's a [link](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t303448-return-identity-after-sql-insert.html) to a thread which discusses this same topic and a possible answer. but there's no verification whether the suggested solution worked or not.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do this is to change to a stored procedure that returns the value you want in a parameter.  Post the code for doing the update you have now and I (or someone else) will show you how to refactor it to use a stored procedure.  It is not hard.